# Hide selected items in the drop-down

Tags: c#, .net

Am using a combo box (drop-down) as a second column in gridview and am populating it using a SELECT query as shown in the code. The first column in the gridview is column headers from a text file and the second column (combo box) displays column values from a table so users can do the mapping.

How can I modify the code below so that if users select a value from the drop-down list, the value doesn't show in the other drop-down lists as it is already mapped? Thanks in advance!

```
public void GV(DataTable table)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table.DefaultView.ToTable(false, "ColumnName");
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection ("server=dev;database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True");
    conn.Open();
    string query = "SELECT Column_Name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CM' ";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    DataTable t1 = new DataTable();
    using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        a.Fill(t1);
    }

    cmb.DataSource = t1;
    cmb.ValueMember = "Customer";
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb);
}
```

Comment: Could you use an if statement or switch statement, something like:

if (comboBox1.Text == "Option one")
{
//Remove that option from the other comboBox
}

Comment: Thanks Steven, but how could I know the name of the comboBox? I added the comboBox using code in the .CS file as shown above and as such can't see how many combo boxes(drop-downs) I have. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: So am I correct in saying that the number of comboBoxes change depending on how much data they retrieve from the database?

Comment: The first column in gridview is not a comboBox and is a list of headers(fields) from a CSV file. The second column in the gridview is a comboBox and is populated from a list of columns in a table using the query SELECT Column_Name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CM'. The structure of this table won't change frequently(we can assume it will never change).

Comment: Would it work to query the number of rows/columns there is in the dataGridView. Sorry I'm still a bit lost on exactly what you are trying to do and why it does not work. 
EDIT: So what you need to do is find all the options in that ComboBox yes?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I have updated my comment(i accidentally hit enter and it got saved). Yes am populating the comboBox with column names from a table as shown in the query.

Comment: Haha no problem, I do that all the time. Could the command "combobox.getitemtext" work in this situation?

Comment: Each comboBox displays all the columns from the table and users would map these columns to the CSV fields and it works perfectly. What users want is to remove the column from the comboBox as they are mapped. For example, let's say there are 4 columns A, B,C D. IF users map A to a CSV field, it the comboBox below should not display A. Hope this is clear. EDIT: I have pasted a screen of this form/gridview here - http://www.filedropper.com/untitled_6

Comment: Okay, I haven't done much with this type of programming particularly (still new to C# also) so some of this is just guessing but could you either use a delete statement for your CSV file, so if its there more than once remove the last one, or could you save all of the items into a variable, and compare that variable to the CSV file and then remove that from the item list if it already exists?

Comment: What am trying to accomplish is figure out a way to hide values in the comboBox that are already select by user in the previous comboBox, similar to how we do in SQL Server Import Export Wizard.

Comment: I'm not following why something like comboBox1.Items.Remove wouldn't work? Also I don't know if it would be easier but I know that the .Settings files visual-studios has seem to work well for holding, well settings or values like this however those I haven't worked with so I don't know if they would work here or not.

Comment: I don't think we can add/remove comboBox items if we are using a data source. Am totally lost here and trying to figure this out since Thursday...

Comment: Do you have a way of finding what the text in the combobox is?

Comment: Yeah, I can gran the contents of the comboBox.